# How can I get all(6867) images from CoinGecko api?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, coingecko

I want to get all the images of the coins(6867 ) that CoinGecko brings, but its API

```
CoinGeckoClient.coins.list()
```

only ruturn {id,symbol,name}
and

```
CoinGeckoClient.coins.all()
```

only return 250 coins

Comment: According to [their API documentation](https://www.coingecko.com/api/documentations/v3#/coins/get_coins_list) there is "no pagination required". I am guessing whatever language-specific wrapper you're using has some built-in pagination? Is there an option or parameter to change the limit you return?

Comment: **From the [CoinGeckoClient Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/coingecko-api#coinsall):** Try and use the `per_page` parameter to the `all()` function call to get all of the coins :)

Answer (score 0):

In case someone is still looking for an answer, their
[image] api seems to do the job. I tried this: https://api.coingecko.com/api/v3/coins/markets?vs_currency=usd&order=market_cap_desc&per_page=5&page=1&sparkline=false but checkout in their [api docs](https://www.coingecko.com/en/api/documentation) urself.